# Convert dentro de uma lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma campo int nullable e que dentro de uma lambda eu preciso popular uma propriedade não nullable. Se eu faço isso:

```
campo1 = Convert.ToInt32(campo2);
```

Eu pego esse erro:

> NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression

Como eu faço para carregar a propriedade não nullable a partir de uma nullable?

Comment: Qual a versão do EF, jovem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
campo1 = campo2 ?? default;
```

O [operador ??](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) é chamado operador de coalescência nula. Ele retornará o operando esquerdo se o operando não for nulo; caso contrário, ele retornará o operando direito.

Comment: esse default é isso mesmo, ou devo colocar 0 caso seja nulo?

Comment: se quiser o valor `0` quando seja `null`, `default` ou `0` será a mesma coisa...

Comment: Deixa eu entender. Isso já faz um tipo de cast para int, correto? Não preciso de uma conversão explícita como havia feito, correto?

Comment: não está a fazer um cast.. esse codigo é o equivalente a este: `campo1 = campo2.HasValue ? campo2.Value : default;`

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar operador ternário na atribuição.
Lê-se: campo2 é null ? então 0 senão campo2.

```
int Campo1 = int.Parse(campo2 == null ? "0" : campo2);
```

Sintaxe:

> condição ? expressão1_se_true : expressão2_se_false

Dê uma olhada mais a fundo  [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/14/11/c_tern1.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi dessa forma:

```
campo1 = (int)campo2;
```

Comment: irá dar erro quando o campo2 for `null`

Comment: Você deve verificar antes se o campo2 é nulo, pois não é possível converter nulo para int